Which type transfer switch for EV to house branch circuits? Two EV outlets. One seems bonded, the other not
I've read a bunch about floating vs bonded neutral generators but very little about vehicle inverters like my KIA EV6 that has two AC outlets. I believe to be safe I need to know if the outlets are bonded or floating so I put a circuit tester on each outlet. The back of car outlet indicates correct (two yellow lights) which I think means it is bonded. The inside car outlet indicates open ground (single center yellow light) which I think means floating. Is my assumption correct?
The maximum output supported is 1800W (15A) using either or both outlets. I would like to put 4 house circuits on a transfer switch knowing I need to keep in mind the max wattage manually.
Should I use a neutral switching transfer switch and plug into the back of car outlet? That moves all neutral/ground reference to the car?
Or, should I use a transfer switch which assumes floating neutral and plug into the inside of car outlet? In this case the transfer switch single neutral and single ground are connected to the house service panel. Does that connect the car neutral/ground to the house service panel or just the transfer switch neutral/ground?
Is everything safe in either of these setups? Am I overcomplicating this?

Here you say "4 house circuits" but in a comment to Triplefault's answer you talk about more than 4.  Can you please clarify if you re planning on an interlock for your entire panel, or a load-side 4-chnnel transfer switch?

Circuit 1. Living room for TV, computer, internet, and lights. Circuit 2. Refrigerator. Circuit 3. Kitchen counter for microwave, coffee pot, and toaster. Circuit 4. Not sure, I'll decide later. My plan is to use transfer switch if I can verify not bonded neutral. Interlock seems more complicated.

I installed a 10 circuit switch and later removed it and installed an interlock.  The interlock was far, far less work, much cheaper, much more versatile, and doesn't clog up the panel with wires.   Maybe with only four circuits the balance tips the other way.

Do you have a voltmeter? If so, you can use it to test the neutral-ground bond presence more firmly.
The full output power voltage can be seen, of course, when the voltmeter reads between the outlet's power and neutral holes. If the ground is bonded to the neutral, then the voltmeter will also read full voltage between the power and ground holes.

The back of car outlet indicates correct (two yellow lights) which I think means it is bonded. The inside car outlet indicates open ground (single center yellow light) which I think means floating.

Confirm this with a voltmeter, and see if the inside-car outlet reads full voltage between the power and ground holes or not:
I've confirmed, there is NO voltage between the power and ground holes on the inside outlet:
Then you can run your main house breaker panel (well, half of your house breaker panel) using the inside-car outlet. Half, because the car only provides 120 volts, not the split-phase 120V/240V the circuit panel normally gets. Search DIY.SE for questions involving running split phase North America circuit panels with 120V generators for the nuances and issues to consider: your situation with the car power will be the same. You'll also have to rearrange your breakers to get the 120V loads on the same panel leg the car is powering.
If you decide to run the main house breaker panel, you may be able to use a simple and much less expensive generator interlock on the panel, if the panel has a compatible interlock available and you can free up the required circuit breaker space needed. A transfer switch that does not switch neutral could also be used, but these are more to a lot more expensive.
No, the outlet tester was wrong, and there IS full voltage between the power and ground holes on both outlets:
The you will need a neutral-switching transfer switch to run your main power panel. Your car has a neutral-ground bond. It will likely be not possible to remove this bond, unless the car's manual has instructions to do so. It will be dangerous to simply remove the ground pin from the extension cord you use to connect the car to the house, in case the idea comes to do that to break the bond: the car's body needs to be grounded to the house ground through that pin, or electric shock could occur.
If by chance there are instructions on how to remove the neutral-ground bond, then remove it and jump up to "there is NO voltage" above to continue the setup. Note that you'll have to put the neutral-ground bond back when you want to use the car's outlet for other situations besides running a house circuit panel.
A frame challenge:
Your car, in addition to only providing 120V, also only provides 15 amps. This rather strongly limits what you can run, at the same time or at all.
No 240V loads. No main house AC. No electric cooking. If the water heater is electric, no hot water. If the heat source in the furnace is electric resistance heat, no house heat. If the mini-splits are 240V, no mini-split AC or heat. No 240V window ACs. Likely no well pump.
What you can run will be limited: One fridge, the TV & internet, the living room lamp with an LED bulb, maybe one 120V window AC in the summer. In winter, if your furnace burns some form of dead dinosaurs, then it might run, too, if its power input is 120V. However, if it has a whole-house blower pushing air through ductwork, that blower may take some 8-10 amps itself, and you may have to choose between the furnace and the fridge. If your well pump amazingly happens to be 120V, you'll get water, but you'll have to add that to the either-or choice of the furnace & fridge.
You'll be constantly choosing what to run when to balance need vs power availability. This "can't run it all" problem fights against connecting the car to the main house panel, especially if you choose the extra cost of a transfer switch, doubly especially if you have that neutral-ground bond still, forcing the extra-expensive neutral-switching transfer switch.
If all you'll have for emergency power is the car, and a 120/240 multi-kilowatt generator is out of the realm of possibility, then a 12 gauge extension cord short as possible to get into the house from the car, a good quality 12-gauge power strip*, and a few more extension cords inside the house to distribute the power, may do in a pinch and will be a lot less expensive than a transfer switch. There are methods to make a 120V furnace into a plug-in appliance or put a generator inlet on it so it can be run through an extension cord.
If you face more than the rare few-hour power outages, and a generator is possible, spend your money in that direction rather than trying to use the car's battery and inverter regularly. Not to mention, power driving your house from the car is power you can't use to drive the car, and you can't refuel the car during a power outage.
( * "Good quality" and "power strip" are hard to find in the same device. It is possible to make a very robust "power strip" using a metal electrical box and regular house power outlets. Ask another question on how to do this if you want.)
The above answer assumes North America split-phase power considerations, based on a web-search showing the KIA's power adapter being a 120V NEMA 5-15 outlet.

Thanks for the multimeter suggestion. I am out of town until next Monday. I will test with my multimeter when I return. I thought the outlet tester would be good but as @jay613 pointed out, it may not be a great tool.

I hear you regarding the sanity of what I'm doing. We lose power for 4-12 hours when a hurricane or ice storm comes through. We don't need heat or cooling. Extension cords to the living room for TV, computer, internet, and lights gets kind of crazy and is difficult to get to some of the UPS plugs. Splicing into that circuit at the service panel is easier. I also want the fridge circuit and counter circuit for MW, coffee pot and toaster. Tapping in at the service panel seems easier. And it's fun to do (if I don't blow everything up).

I agree with you on the ease of using an interlocked panel connection for backup power, it is the bee's knees, especially if regular outages happen. If you mark all your breakers so you turn off all 240's and all unnecessary 120's, and ensure that all the desired 120's are on the powered leg, then you should be good with an interlock, if you can officially get rid of the neutral ground bond. All that's left is balancing high-power loads.

The outlet tester was correct. With the voltmeter, back outlet showed 120V between hot/neutral and 120V hot/ground. Inside car outlet was 120V hot/neutral and 1V hot/ground. Weird that they are different. I would have thought both would be bonded since it seems the general intent is to plug in devices.   I think I understand the potential problems with using the bonded outlet and plugging into the house with its bonded neutral. Not sure others using a transfer switch understand the potential problems.   Anyway, I had never heard of the panel interlock but looked into it. Pretty cool.

Continuing w prev comment... My panel is full but I do have four large singles that the panel allows me to use narrow brkrs. That would leave room at the top for an interlock. Need to see if one exists for my panel. I'd have some rewiring to do in the panel (no wire splicing, I think and less messy than transfer switch) but will have to consider if it's worth it for 15A. It'd be pretty cool to be able to move around the house. Any thoughts on which way to go? I'm leaning toward interlock.

RTFM !!!
I don't think I've ever made that the first line of a post but in this case I could stop there. It is the entire answer.  Some vehicles especially those designed and marketed for vehicle to house power, will detect connection to your house and automatically switch from internal bonding to your bonding.  If not,  most will be internally bonded, within the inverter in a way you cannot see or modify. But maybe not all? There is only one way to know how your vehicle works, and it is the manual, not a $5 residential ground tester.
Once you know how your vehicle behaves, you can come back here and ask questions about how to deal with grounding given its specific capabilities.
A neutral switching transfer switch is likely to be too expensive compared to, in my interpretation, the scope of what you're trying to do.  Given the very limited power, if you can't use a cheap transfer switch you are better off with extension cords. You don't have the CO issues with extension cords that you do with gas generators, and the task of manually controlling load is built into the solution.

I did RTFM and searched the web for weeks. Nowhere is the neutral/ground bond discussed for the KIA EV6  Finally decided to ask in this forum for a way to convincingly understand what the outlets are. @Triplefault gave me a good suggestion. See my comments to him regarding the sanity of what I'm doing. Extension cords are a bit of a pain and I don't need much power so I thought a transfer switch would be fun to install. I agree a neutral switching transfer switch would be too expensive but the non seems worth it. Hence my desire to understand what I have to work with from the car.
